# A family of probability measures satisfying an integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Consider the problem of finding a family of probability measures $(\mu_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}( \mathbb{R}))$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \mu_t(dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \mu_0(dx) + \int_0^t ds \int_{ \mathbb{R} } (A_s \varphi)(x) \mu_s(dx)
$$
for all real-valued smooth functions $\varphi$ with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$. Here,
$$
(A_s \varphi)(x) := a(s,x) \varphi'(x) + b ( s, x)
 \varphi''(x)
$$
for sufficiently nice functions $a$ and $b$.

I have come across the following reasoning on why the solution to the equation is not unique:

> If $A$ has an invariant probability measure $\mu$ then any family of probability measures $(\mu_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with $\mu_0 = \mu$ solves the equation above.

What does it mean for the differential operator $A$ to have an invariant probability measure $\mu$? Is it always possible to find such a measure?